# Ricci Flow on a Sphere of radius r

Tags: differential-geometry, ricci-flow

Let $(M, g)$ be an $n$-sphere of radius $r$ with metric $g$ where $g = r^{2}g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}$, $g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}$ being the standard metric on the unit $n$-sphere. It is well known that $Ric_{g}=(n-1)g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}$. If we apply Ricci flow on $M$ does the shape of the sphere change? The evolution equation is $\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t}g =\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t} (r^{2}g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}) = -2Ric_{g}$.

Now the left-hand side should give us $2r\dot{r} g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}+\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}} $. However, most books and notes on Ricci flow say:

$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t} (r^{2}g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}) = -2Ric_{g}$ 
$ \implies 2r\dot{r}g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}= -2(n-1)g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}$

$\implies r\dot{r}=-(n-1)$.

My question is what happens to the term $\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}$? Does the metric $g_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}$ not change under the flow? Why? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The metric $g_{S^{n}}$ is "constant". Perhaps you're conflating $g_{S^{n}}$ with $g$...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metric $g_{\mathbb S^n}$ by definition does not change. Indeed, you are making an (educated) **guess** that when you apply Ricci flow to the sphere of radius $r_0$, the solution is of the form 
$$ g(t)  = r(t)^2 g_{\mathbb S^n},$$

here $g_{\mathbb S^n}$ is the fixed metric (that is, the only term that involves $t$ are from $r(t)$). Using this guess,

$$ \partial_t g(t) = \partial_t ( r(t)^2 g_{\mathbb S^n}) = 2r \dot r\  g_{\mathbb S^n}$$

and 
$$Ric_{g(t)} =  (n-1) g_{\mathbb S^n}$$

(the Ricci curvature of with respect to $r^2 g_{\mathbb S^n}$ is [the same as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Behavior_under_conformal_rescaling) that of $g_{\mathbb S^n}$)

That's why when you set

$$\partial_t g(t) = -2Ric_{g(t)},$$

one obtains

$$ 2r\dot r g_{\mathbb S^n} = -2(n-1) g_{\mathbb S^n}\Rightarrow r\dot r = -(n-1).$$

Integrating you have $r(t) = \sqrt{r_0^2 - 2(n-1) t}$, or

$$g(t) = (r_0^2 - 2(n-1)t) g_{\mathbb S^n}.$$
Now you have guessed a correct solution to the Ricci flow. By uniqueness, this is the solution to the Ricci flow equation.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I am just now seeing it. I wrote a post a while ago about a "cheat" solution for $n=2$ here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097512/extinction-time-of-a-2-sphere-under-ricci-flow is it correct to say that in this particular case ($n=2$) the extinction time is $\frac{r_0}{2}$?